# PHP + AJAX code - Display data on selecting a value from a list

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to display data from database(MySQL) based on the option fields selected. I have two fields as shown below :

**Select a Health Block : .......(list) 

Select the year       : .......(list)**

When I select health block and year, data from database should be displayed on the same page itself. I've tried the following code. Actually the code works if I've only one option ('year') to be selected. What I need is to pass both the values (Health block and Year) to the page (getblock2.php) where I've written the code to retrieve data from database. Can anybody please help me to figure out where the problem is?

### Mainpage

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var str11;
var str22;

function showB(str2)
{
    str22=str2;
}

function showBlock2(str)
{
showB();
str11=str;
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getblock2.php?q="+str11+"&h="+str22,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Select a Health block
<select name="h" onChange="showB(this.value)">
<option value="1">H1</option>
<option value="2">H2</option>
</select>
<br/>
Select a year
<select name="yr" onChange="showBlock2(this.value)">
<option>2012</option>
<option>2013</option>
</select>
<div id="txtHint" style="width:570px; height:auto" >
                            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### getblock2.php

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
$q=$_GET["q"];
$h=$_GET['h'];
$q="select Total_Cases from epidemics where Year1=$q and Hid=$h";
$r=mysql_query($q);
$i=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($r))
    {
    $i++;
    echo $i." ".$row[0]."<br/>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why are there <html> and <body> tags in your getblock2.php response? They are unneeded when just inserting HTML into your DOM. (On top of that you also have severe SQL-injections here.) Could you specify more clearly what is wrong? And is there a reason why you are not using a library for your AJAX-call like jQuery?

Comment: What is the error your getting?

Comment: How can I get the str22 variable value in function showBlock2()?

Comment: @MShahzadKhan Actually, the value of variable str22 is captured with onChange() event. But how can I access the same variable in function showBlock2() so that the variable can be passed to the page getblock2.php along with the first value?

Comment: You've also got some glaring SQL Injection vulnerabilities there.

Comment: Post your 'select' HTML here, so i can let you know the solution.

Comment: @MrP I just pasted only a part of the code...Rest of the page have some sort of html design.

Comment: @MShahzadKhan <select name="h" onChange="showB(this.value)">
<option value="1">H1</option>
<option value="2">H2</option>
</select> <br/> <select name="yr" onChange="showBlock2(this.value)">
<option>2012</option>
<option>2013</option>
</select>

Comment: Ok check my answer for optimized code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `str22` is not being assigned when you call `showBlock2()` on changing year. So replace the line

```
showB();
```

with

```
showB(document.getElementsByName("h")[0].value);
```

This would work when you select health and then year, no need to call showB() on changing health list.

**EDITED (Optimized Code):**

The following code has been altered from your source.

**Mainpage**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showBlock2()
{
    var str11=document.getElementsByName("h")[0].value;
    var str22=document.getElementsByName("yr")[0].value;
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getblock2.php?q="+str11+"&h="+str22,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Select a Health block
<select name="h" onChange="showBlock2()">
    <option value="1">H1</option>
    <option value="2">H2</option>
</select>
<br/>
Select a year
<select name="yr" onChange="showBlock2()">
    <option>2012</option>
    <option>2013</option>
</select>
<div id="txtHint" style="width:570px; height:auto" >
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that only `function showBlock2()` is used for onchange on both dropdowns, so the div `txtHint` is updated at each change. Also no parameters passed.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion :-) . It works fine now. But, can you please provide me the optimized code to do the same?

Comment: Thank u...It really helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

Just remove

```
showB()
```

It will work fine. As you have already values in both variables. Just `showB()` function is making the variable empty again.

Here is the optimized code. It can work in both cases, which ever select option you select first.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var healthValue = "";
var yearValue = "";

function showB(str2)
{
  healthValue = str2;

if(yearValue != '')
{
    callAjax(); 
}
}

function showBlock2(str)
{
yearValue = str;

if(healthValue != '')
{
    callAjax(); 
}
 }


 function callAjax()
 {

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","getblock2.php?q="+healthValue+"&h="+yearValue,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. But still its not displaying the result

Comment: Navigate to ajax page directly through browser like http://yoursite/getblock2.php?q=healthValue&h=yearValue  -- You will see the error.